# I am having a null pointer exception and i'm not sure where it is in my code

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I am having issues with various exceptions in my code. The class is designed to find all folders/subfolders on the computer and list them as an ArrayList. It does not care about the files in them. Here is the code. please help, I have been frustrated with this for a week now.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Detector
{
   private ArrayList<String> paths;

   public Detector()
   {
      File[] roots = File.listRoots();
      for(File drive : roots)
      {
         getPaths(drive.listFiles());
      }
   }
   public Detector(String str)
   {

      File[] bob = new File(str).listFiles();
      getPaths(bob);
   }

   public void getPaths(File[] files)
   {
      for (File file : files)
      {
          if(file.isDirectory())
          {
             paths.add(file.getName());
             getPaths(file.listFiles());
          }
      }
   }

   public ArrayList<String> getPathList()
   {
      return paths;
   }

   public void printPaths()
   {
      for(String str: this.getPathList())
      {
         System.out.println(str);
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
         Detector tom = new Detector("/F:");
         tom.printPaths();
   }
}
```

Comment: not sure `"/F:"` is really supposed to work

Comment: you never initialize your arraylist ...

Answer (score 2):

You never initialized `paths`:

```
private ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Note that I've also used a type parameter of `String` here, as you should. In general try to stay away from using [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: Want to mention Liskov?

Comment: @Bohemian What do you mean?

Comment: [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): the type of `paths` should be declared as the abstract type `List<String>` if best practices are followed (not as fthe concrete implementation type `ArrayList<String>`)

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect syntax at this line

```
private ArrayList<String> paths;
```

You are not initializing arraylist properly. in order to initialize it properly you would have to do

```
private ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note: I did not put `String` inside `<>` as its redundant in java 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

***Additional remark:***

`File.listFiles()` might return `null` which might be your NullPointerException. So do:

```
public void getPaths(File[] files)
{
    if (files == null) {
        return;
    }
```

And Java 7 has a [Files.walkFileTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor%29) which comes with a couple of new classes, but is worth getting accustomed to.